# Fazer ordenação de um Array

Tags: java, array, classificação

Tenho minha class `ItemList`

```
    public class ItemListPropaganda {

        private int iconeRid;
        private String texto;
        private int valor;

        public ItemListPropaganda(String texto, int iconeRid, int valor) {
            this.texto = texto;
            this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
            this.valor = valor;
        }

        public int getIconeRid() {
            return iconeRid;
        }

        public void setIconeRid(int iconeRid) {
            this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
        }

        public String getTexto() {
            return texto;
        }

        public void setTexto(String texto) {
            this.texto = texto;
        }

        public int getvalor() {
            return valor;
        }

        public void setvalor(int valor) {
            this.valor = valor;
        }
}
```

Tenho na minha class principal:

```
private ArrayList<ItemListPropaganda > itens;
```

Como posso fazer para ordenar por valor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode implementar a interface Comparator e usá-la para o Collections ordenar sua lista.

Por exemplo, na API 19:

```
Collections.sort(itens, new Comparator<ItemListPropaganda>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(ItemListPropaganda o1, ItemListPropaganda o2)
            {
                return Integer.compare(o1.getValor(), o2.getValor());
            }
});
```

Para fins de compatibilidade com APIs inferiores o `Integer.compare(arg1, arg2)` (só está disponível a partir da API 19) deve ser evitado, como abaixo:

```
Collections.sort(itens, new Comparator<ItemListPropaganda>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(ItemListPropaganda o1, ItemListPropaganda o2)
            {
                if(o1.getValor() < o2.getValor()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1.getValor() == o2.getValor()) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
});
```

Com isso, sua lista será ordenada de acordo com o atributo que você quiser.

Comment: estou utilizando API 19, poderia implementar um exemplo dessa condição?