# Fazer uma Ordenação por data

Tags: android, classificação

Tenho a seguinte class quero ordenar os valores dela por data

```
public class ItemListAnuncios {

    private String texto;
    private String data;

    public ItemListPropaganda(String texto, String data) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.data= data;
    }

    public int getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto= texto;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data= data;
    }
```

Tenho na minha class principal:

```
private ArrayList<ItemListAnuncios > itens;
```

Como posso fazer para ordenar? é melhor eu enviar no formato date ou String mesmo?

Comment: Felipe, de uma olhada nesta resposta. Acredito que possa te ajudar: [Sort ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18441978/1898543)

Comment: @Felipe, como sua data está como string é bom você colocar o formato dela também.

Comment: Veja a resposta a esta pergunta: [Fazer ordenação de um Array](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37012/2541)